# EXIM4: smtp transport process returned non-zero status 0x000b: terminated by signal 11

Tags: smtp, exim

I'm getting this error only for a specific domain. I have tried to set the option:

`hosts_avoid_tls=*`

in remote_smtp but it is still not working. This is also causing issues with other domains as some domains require secure auth so I have reverted to old config.

System in exim 4.89 on Debian stretch (9) freshly installed.

Seeking for some help.

Comment: Enable debugging and verbose logging then look at logs for some more significant information.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for comment. I realized that the DNS servers for a particular IP were not working. Changing resolv.conf to Google DNS solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that the IP I was using for my email server had a bad reputation. I did a checkup on http://ipremoval.sms.symantec.com/lookup/ and requested an IP investigation. Once sorted from their side everything started working properly.